# Datatables: Select row with given ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've set up a datatables plugin and created a new table from an JSON file:

```
var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({

    ajax: "list.json",
    columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ]
});
```

Now I want to add an `.active` class to a row with a given id:

```
table.on( 'xhr', function () {
  table.row("#id_1").addClass("active");
}
```

(the id's for the rows has been defined during the plugin setup and are in place). However, I get this error:

```
undefined is not a function
```

like it can't find a row with this ID, however I do have it. Any ideas?

Comment: `table.row("#id_1")` may not be returning `jQuery` wrapped object.. Try `$(table.row("#id_1")).addClass`

Comment: Rayon, that was a very good point! You are my saviour again. Luca completed the answer with a mention of node() too! Thank you very much! I have a lot to learn yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Datatables `.row()` method doesn't return a DOM Node, you need to get it with `.node()` after selecting it.

`var row = table.row("#id_1").node(); 
$(row).addClass('active');`

[Datatables .row()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row())

[Datatables .node()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node())